# How to check whether there is any datetime value in a column of a row dynamically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, c#-4.0

I have written code like

```
for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
{
    foreach (DataColumn dc in ds.Tables[0].Columns)
    {
        dc.ColumnName = dc.ColumnName.ToString().Replace(" ", "-").Replace("%", "_").Replace(",", "").Replace("'", "").Replace("(", "").Replace(")", "").Replace(":", "").Replace("?", "").Replace("/", "").Replace("!", "");

        ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][dc.ColumnName] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][dc.ColumnName].ToString().Replace("<br/>", "\r");
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][dc.ColumnName].DataType == System.Type.GetType("System.DateTime"))
        { 

        }
    }
  }
```

I want to check that any row contains any datetime column or not.

The above code is throwing error in

```
      ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][dc.ColumnName].DataType
```

line... Please help me!!!

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Error 22 'object' does not contain a definition for 'DataType' and no extension method 'DataType' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: So where does the `DataType` property you were expecting to use live?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use "is" instead:

```
 if(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][dc.ColumnName] is DateTime)
 {
 }
```

I would suggest that you also check if the column/value is null or not.
Otherwise you might get a NullException.

Edit: 
You could also use:

```
if(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][dc.ColumnName].GetType() == typeof(DateTime))
```

Answer (score 1):

take your column name in string and parse

```
 string st=ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][dc.ColumnName].ToString();
try
{
DateTime dateTime;
DateTime.TryParse(st, out dateTime);
}
catch()
{
}
```

check if success otherwise not..datetime